# Do Javascript function on certain height

Tags: javascript, function

If you take a look at this link and scroll down: http://templates.entheosweb.com/template_number/live_demo.asp?TemplateID=51090

You see that if you scroll down, animations are displayed. Javascript functions are triggered at a certain height and I also want to achieve that effect. But I have no idea where to start. How can I trigger a function at a certain height?

Comment: the reason you've probably not found any tutorials on how to do this is because it has nothing to do with "height" - it has to do with the current scroll position - and there are far better examples that animate back and forth as you scroll up and down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var hasFired = false;

    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 250 && !hasFired) {
        hasFired = true;
        // do something when scrolling down
    }

    if (document.body.scrollTop < 250 && hasFired {
        hasFired = false;
        // do something when scrolling up, and enable the scroll-down event to fire once again
    }
});
```

The second `if()` is optional.

Comment: Thank you! One other question, is it also possible to run a function when a certain div is displayed when I scroll?

Comment: Yes but please open another question for that :) you may link it here so I can find it later. That's a relatively complex thing to do, though, so if you aren't comfortable with actual coding, consider some library such as AOS (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use scroll listener and at particular hight, you can call your funtion :-

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()}; 

function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop == 250) {
   myCustomFunction();
}
}

function myCustomFunction {
  // define your logic here
 }
```

Comment: I put in my logic: alert("test"). But it didn't work.

Comment: where you putted alert

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply to this sooner and created another answer but I'm still a pleb with no points. Basically the problem of this solution is that the `scrollTop` is unlikely to be exactly 250px so the check should be for `>= 250px`. But then the problem would be that it will keep firing continuously while scrolling down so a `hasFired` flag should be implemented too.

Comment: This simple example , one can decide range in logic

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of libraries([for example](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)) to achieve this animation, google for them.
And if you want to write your own custom logic than check the `window.scroll` function of JavaScript.